# GFCI breaker on a MWBC (Shared common)

Tags: gfci, mwbc

We are doing kitchen reno. We had to replace the main breaker panel.  Local code requires we use arc fault breakers.  This is not an issue for most of the project, however, the inspector is insisting that we have combo arc fault with dual function of GFCI. The Arc faults work fine, however the GFCI keep tripping.

I explained to the inspector that this is a shared natural circuit and the GFCI will trip as the current coming back will not match what is going out. I will install GFCI at all the outlets to cover that requirement, however, he is insisting the breaker needs to be GFCI.

Can anyone point me to  somewhere in the NEC where I can prove to him that having the GFCI at the outlet is legit and for all the shared natural circuits we will use combo arc fault only, not dual function.  I know some of you will tell me to run new wires for the MWBC so they all have their own neutral.

Any other  suggestions ?

Comment: Is this a city inspector who is holding up a permit here?  Or is this a home inspector of some buyer?  Also, what type of service panel is this - Eaton? Siemens? GE? Square D?

Comment: Is the circuit multi-wire/shared-neutral through its entire length, or just for the homerun?

Comment: It's a permit and city inspector.  We have done dozens of these and this is the first guy I have a problem with.   I have 4 shared common circuits coming out of the breaker box.   The common is shared for the complete run (home run and beyond)   This is common practice and is perfectly legal.  This inspector is wrong.  I just can't find a paragraph (or paragraphs)  in the NEC to make it perfectly clear to him.  We just finished 3 other jobs in 2 other  jurisdictions with arch fault breakers and GFCI at the outlets where needed. (kitchen , garage etc)  and all passed inspection no problems.

Comment: it's a GE box and breakers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First require / request the inspector to cite the code # to write a violation ,,, that is a legal requirement in my state, what state are you in? Even in my state under the 2020 nfpa70 code no AFCI is required on the 2 required 20 amp kitchen circuits that are GFCI protected,,,I have seen problems with inspectors for DIY including my self,,, moved to a county where I had not worked the inspector tried to pull ? Until I asked for the requirements, he quickly backed off when I brought out my code book and mentioned my license from memory, just saying sounds fishy to me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have a license electrician.  He did not know you can't use a GFCI breaker on a MWBC until I explained it to him with fancy drawings and specs.   He is working with the inspector.  The inspector just said "don't argue wit me".   So, we have a plan :)